# Multiple screencapturing with Chrome ScreenCastify

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screenshot, screen-capture, screencast

I want to use Chrome Screen castify to caputure multiple windows/tabs simultaneuosly.
Can somebody help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a work around for this, by creating different google-chrome profiles. Is a space consuming alternative, but worked for me.